# how to open non default browsers when doing npm start for a react project

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have a react project that I am running using npm. When I do npm start, it launches on my default browser:- google chrome.

I would like to launch on firefox, safari and internet explorer for manual testing. I prefer don't making changes to package.json due to one time use.Any ideas on how to go about?

Specs

node -p process.arch: x64

node -p process.platform: darwin

npm info react version 16.4.0

macOS 10.13.4 (17E199)

Comment: Can you post what your package.json looks like?

Comment: try update packages: `npm update`

Answer (score 10):

Create an environment file `.env` at the root of the project directory and add following entry

```
BROWSER=firefox
```

For a complete list of `.env` file configuration, you can check [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration) - https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration

Comment: simple and efficient. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

As I read on [the script that runs when you run npm start](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/next/packages/react-dev-utils/openBrowser.js), you may set an environment variable called BROWSER before running the `npm start`

For example (on linux):

```
(export BROWSER=firefox;  npm start)
```

also, you may open the browsers after starting:

```
npm start &
firefox http://localhost:3000
safari http://localhost:3000
```

Save it to a something.sh and run this shell script. If you are on windows, you may do something similar on .bat script

Answer (score 2):

you can install global node package called opn-cli then you can run the command.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/opn-cli

Sample command:

`npm start & opn http://localhost:4200 -- firefox & opn http://localhost:4200 -- chrome`

Answer (score 0):

First Install This:-

```
npm install --save cross-env
```

Than and update package.json file `scripts` only :-

**Old**

```
"scripts": {
   "start": "cross-env BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

},

**Update**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "cross-env BROWSER=none react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```